# Manual parameter updates using tf.assign in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given the following example code (to work with):

```
# Generate random data
x_train = np.random.rand(64, 16, 16, 8)
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 5, 64)
one_hot = np.zeros((len(y_train), 5))
one_hot[list(np.indices((len(y_train),))) + [y_train]] = 1
y_train = one_hot

# Model definition
class FeedForward(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 16, 16, 8], name="input_x")
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5], name="input_y")

        with tf.name_scope("conv1"):
            kernel_shape=[3, 3, 8, 8]
            w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(kernel_shape, stddev=0.1), name="weight")
            conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(self.x, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", name="conv")

        with tf.name_scope("conv2"):
            kernel_shape=[3, 3, 8, 4]
            w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(kernel_shape, stddev=0.1), name="weight")
            conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", name="conv")

        out = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv2)

        with tf.name_scope("output"):
            kernel_shape=[out.get_shape()[1].value, 5]
            w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(kernel_shape, stddev=0.1), name="weight")
            self.scores = tf.matmul(out, w)
            predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, axis=1, name="predictions")

        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores, labels=self.y))

        correct_predictions = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(self.y, axis=1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

I wish to perform a custom weight update step, ie., aside from the weight update on each iteration, I would like to subtract some fixed value from my weight parameter as below:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)      

    with sess.as_default():
        ffn = FeedForward()

        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-2)
        grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(ffn.loss)

        updated_gv = []
        for g, w in grads_and_vars:
            # perform update on weights aside from ouput weights
            if ("weight" in w.name) and ("output" not in w.name):
                # some weight update
                w_update = tf.Variable.assign(w, w - tf.constant(1.0, shape=w.get_shape()))
            updated_gv.append([g, w])
        # next two lines are not required here                
        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(updated_gv, global_step=global_step)

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        def train_step(x_batch, y_batch):
            feed_dict = {

            }
            _, step, _update, loss, accuracy = sess.run([train_op, global_step, w_update, ffn.loss, ffn.accuracy], 
                                                        feed_dict={ffn.x: x_batch, ffn.y: y_batch})
            print("step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(step, loss, accuracy))

        batch_size = 32
        s_idx = - batch_size

        for batch_index in range(2):
            s_idx += batch_size
            e_idx = s_idx + batch_size
            x_batch = x_train[s_idx:e_idx]
            y_batch = y_train[s_idx:e_idx]

            train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
            current_step = tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step)
```

However, the above code (and other similar variations of it) do not affect the actual weights. I assume that any assignments using `tf.Variable.assign...` or `tf.assign...` are made into some copy of the original variable.

What is the most meaningful way to perform the intended update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)` this line just returns an empty list in your code.

If you want to perform a (manual) weight change after calculating and applying the gradient, you can break it into two steps:

`sess.run([your normal gradient step])` and then

`sess.run([your weight update ops])`

Comment: Yes, `update_ops` was meant for `batch_norm` part of the code that I have omitted, so its pretty much useless here.

So you're saying if I run `w_update` _after_ applying gradients it'll work? Why is that?

Comment: `sess.run([your normal gradient step])` will do `w = w - gradient` and `sess.run([your weight update ops])` will do `w = w - 1.0`. So eventually you are doing `w = w - gradient - 1`. Is that what you are trying to do about "aside from the weight update on each iteration, I would like to subtract some fixed value from my weight parameter."?

Comment: That is the intended update, yes. And it works, so thank you! 

What I mean to ask is why is the above any different from performing `sess.run([normal gradient step, weight update op])`?

Comment: The code above works to certain extent. The problem is that fetches does not have a specific order in the execution and your computation graph does not specify an order as well. The easiest solution is to handle the order explicitly like what I did.